# Webservice for looking up radio codes for a car?

Tags: audio

I've browsed the web a bit, and often come across some shady folks asking donations/free advertising in exchange for getting a radio code to use when connecting a radio to a car, eg. after replacing the battery. Surely there is some webservice that they query to check for the 4 digit number?

Where could I find one such service? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A web service anyone could use to unlock radios would defeat the purpose of securing the radio with a code, wouldn't it? The dealership is where you need to go or better yet, check your owners manual it will tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: Well, it's an aftermarket stereo, with the manual some 8 years gone :)

Comment: A critical piece of information missing from the original post.

Comment: Hmm, managed to find it actually. But it doesn't seem to have a security code though. It has one sticker with the product model (eg. A123BC) and its model code (A123WXYZ), and another card with its full serial number (eg. A123VA123456) along with the text that it is used when identifying a stolen stereo. Perhaps the security code is part of one of those codes, but there was no such comment in the manual and the card.

Answer (score 0):

The code is usually on a card or tag supplied by the dealer when the car was new. If this is a second-hand unit then you are more challenged.

Some dealerships can sort the code for free, others charge a token amount, others still charge lots...

Some manufacturers have the radio set so there is a default code or set of keypresses to unlock the radio - this is the case for my model...